# Which tool allows to generate such nice source code pictures?

Tags: code-visualization

examples below. I am pretty sure that there is online free tool that can do it. But I lost a link :(

May be someone has the link?

http://habrastorage.org/storage2/c43/58e/013/c4358e0133268ad6afa9a9f9ef11c4af.png 
[image]

[image]

Comment: I really like https://carbon.now.sh

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This can be done with this tool: http://instaco.de/

Comment: WOW! I never knew that... Now I can save lesser time on making those presentations :) +1 for the link.

Comment: This is a modern version: https://carbon.now.sh/

Comment: Modern version? It's totally different...

Answer (score 11):

We've recently created such tool [team411.github.com/src2img](https://team411.github.io/src2img/)
Yeah, we know about instacode.es, but the key point was a creation of clean highlighted source code images to use in speeches, presentations, etc.

Comment: That's pretty neat :)

Comment: You don't have an API we could use to get images?

Comment: @AlecHewitt no, it has no backend and uses `html2canvas` lib to create images right in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

1. Use an editor like GEdit and set the theme to oblivion.
2. Open any source code file - eg: php, C++
3. Get screenshots as you like
4. Edit the screens (rotate/skew) on a graphics program like GIMP or InkScape

And you have your result.